# date in future for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I am trying to make a validation that will validate that the entered date is in future and that the selected date is in the next 7 days.

In order to validate if the date is in future I use;

```
valid_until.future?
```

and this one works fine, but to make a validation to check if the date selected is withing 7 days from now?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
valid_until.future? && valid_until < 7.days.since(Time.now).to_date
```

Comment: I am getting "comparison of Date with Time failed"

Comment: How do you use that code as part of a validates definition in a Rails model? I tried: `validates :start_time, 
  self.start_time.future? && valid_until < 14.days.since(Time.now).to_date` but that didn't work.